# How to ignore enter button on keyboard for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

For flutter web, pressing enter triggers an event. How can I ignore the use case where the user presses the enter key on their keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way?

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

MaterialApp(
    shortcuts: Map.of(WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts) 
        ..remove(LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)), //<-- add this to materialapp
    ...
)
```

to ignore keyboard on widget i had many search and i found a solution, but im not sure about it:

you can use [ShortcutManager](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShortcutManager-class.html)

```
Shortcuts.manager(
        manager: ShortcutManager(
          shortcuts: Map.of(WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts)
            ..remove(LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter))
            ..remove(LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.numpadEnter)),
        ),
        child: TextField(),
      ),
```

i hope this works

Comment: how do I add this to a textfield widget instead of the material app?

Comment: checkout updated answer